# oversecretion of the thyroid gland

Tags: human-biology

What are the reasons for the oversecretion  of thyroxin in the thyroid glands?
Its name was mentioned in my book but there was no explanation.

What are its symptoms,can it be fatal?

Comment: what book? where else have you looked? this is a relatively straightforward question/answer if you search the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elevated levels of thyroid hormone in the blood is called thyrotoxicosis. If this is due to a hyperfunction of the thyroid gland, it is known as hyperthyroidism. In common parlance, these terms are often interchanged.

Although a simple google search would tell you more, I add some detail here.

Hyperthyroid can have various causes. There can be a functional cancerous/ non-cancerous mass in the thyroid gland producing the hormone. Or as in graves disease which is an autoimmune condition where antibodies mimic to stimulate the thyroid gland to hyperfunction.

Non hyperthyroid causes of thyrotoxicosis include inflammation of thyroid or thyroiditis, where preformed hormone is released. It can also occur sometimes in a condition called struma ovarii where the tumor in the ovary turns into a thyroid like mass producing the hormone. Another possible case is an iatrogenic one where the the problem is due to the patient taking exogenous thyroid hormone.

Thyrotoxicosis is not fatal and can be controlled by drugs. Symptoms include cardiac problems, high BMR, ocular changes (bulging eyes), diarrhea and many more.
A special case of Graves disease called thyroid storm is a medical emergency and can be fatal.

Heres the medscape link for further reference. http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/121865-overview

Comment: what is a thyroid thaw?

Comment: There can be a functional cancerous/ non-cancerous mass in the thyroid thaws producing the hormone.

Comment: Typo there! Corrected :)

Comment: Your answers are usually of much better quality than this one, which has a lot of errors. It makes me wonder if you actually read the medscape article. -1 (Sorry)

Comment: @anongoodnurse I actually wrote this up from Robbins pathology. I gave the Medscape one as an online reference. Frankly speaking I dint read i dint read it. Anyway, could you please point out the errors?